# Как получить с модели формы доступ к сущности?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть класс Car(Active Record) и есть класс Bike(Active Record).
В классе Car есть связь с Bike hasmany. 
Создана форма(extends Model) для добавления новых записей в Car;
В класс формы передаю модель Car и сохраняю через save.

Вопрос, в классе формы Car мне нужно получить доступ для сохранения данных в Bike.
Как это можно реализовать?*

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть структуру таблиц и их связь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом link(), при условии, что модель bike уже в базе.

```
$bike = Bike::findOne(123);
$car = new Car();
$car->link('car', $bike);
```